# Compilation error with messages to self using package msc

Tags: errors, compilation-error, msc

I'm creating a sequence diagram using the [development sty of `msc`](https://satoss.uni.lu/software/mscpackage/#develop) but I'm getting an `Undefined control sequence` error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\GenericError  ...                                
                                                    #4  \errhelp \@err@     ...
l.19 \end
         {msc}
```

In the example below I can use the command `\s` and math operator `\CMAC` when sending messages from A to B or vice-versa but not *to self* such as B to B. The first three messages work, the last two messages fail.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{msc}
\newcommand*{\s}[1]{\mathit{#1}}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\CMAC}{CMAC}
\begin{document}
\begin{msc}{mwe}
    \declinst{A}{}{A}
    \declinst{B}{}{B}
    \mess{$\CMAC_{\s{k}}(x)$}{A}{B}  % works
    \nextlevel
    \mess{$\CMAC$}{A}{B}             % works
    \nextlevel
    \mess{$x$}{B}{B}                 % works
    \nextlevel
    \mess{$\CMAC$}{B}{B}           % FAILS
    \nextlevel
    \mess{$\s{fails}$}{B}{B}       % FAILS
\end{msc}
\end{document}
```

Direct link to `msc.sty`: https://satoss.uni.lu/software/mscpackage/development/msc.sty

I don't know if I'm doing something wrong, or if it could be a bug in `msc`. Any idea why I'm getting this error?

#### Log file

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2019.3.5)  8 MAR 2021 17:00
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**tmp.tex
(./tmp.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.18> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
Package: amsmath 2017/09/02 v2.17a AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip43

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks14
\ex@=\dimen103
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen104
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty
Package: amsopn 2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count87
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 213.
\uproot@=\count88
\leftroot@=\count89
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 375.
\classnum@=\count90
\DOTSCASE@=\count91
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 472.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 475.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 596.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box26
\strutbox@=\box27
\big@size=\dimen105
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 712.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 713.
\macc@depth=\count92
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count93
\dotsspace@=\muskip10
\c@parentequation=\count94
\dspbrk@lvl=\count95
\tag@help=\toks15
\row@=\count96
\column@=\count97
\maxfields@=\count98
\andhelp@=\toks16
\eqnshift@=\dimen106
\alignsep@=\dimen107
\tagshift@=\dimen108
\tagwidth@=\dimen109
\totwidth@=\dimen110
\lineht@=\dimen111
\@envbody=\toks17
\multlinegap=\skip44
\multlinetaggap=\skip45
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks18
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2817.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2818.
) (./msc.sty
msc version 2.0. (2014/10/29)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks19
\pgfutil@tempdima=\dimen112
\pgfutil@tempdimb=\dimen113

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-lists.t
ex)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def
\pgfutil@abb=\box28
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ms/everyshi.sty
Package: everyshi 2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex
Package: pgfrcs 2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.31)
))
Package: pgf 2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.15)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2017/06/01 v1.1a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks20
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2017/06/25 v1.2c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 99.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for pdftex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen114
\Gin@req@width=\dimen115
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
Package: pgfsys 2014/07/09 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.48)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks21
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks22

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.code.t
ex
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks23
))
\pgf@x=\dimen116
\pgf@y=\dimen117
\pgf@xa=\dimen118
\pgf@ya=\dimen119
\pgf@xb=\dimen120
\pgf@yb=\dimen121
\pgf@xc=\dimen122
\pgf@yc=\dimen123
\w@pgf@writea=\write3
\r@pgf@reada=\read1
\c@pgf@counta=\count99
\c@pgf@countb=\count100
\c@pgf@countc=\count101
\c@pgf@countd=\count102
\t@pgf@toka=\toks24
\t@pgf@tokb=\toks25
\t@pgf@tokc=\toks26
 (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg
File: pgf.cfg 2008/05/14  (rcs-revision 1.7)
)
Driver file for pgf: pgfsys-pdftex.def

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-pdftex.def
File: pgfsys-pdftex.def 2014/10/11  (rcs-revision 1.35)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-pdf.de
f
File: pgfsys-common-pdf.def 2013/10/10  (rcs-revision 1.13)
)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.code.
tex
File: pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex 2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
\pgfsyssoftpath@smallbuffer@items=\count103
\pgfsyssoftpath@bigbuffer@items=\count104
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.code.
tex
File: pgfsysprotocol.code.tex 2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 225.
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1348.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1352.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1364.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1366.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1367.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
Package: pgfcore 2010/04/11 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex
\pgfmath@dimen=\dimen124
\pgfmath@count=\count105
\pgfmath@box=\box29
\pgfmath@toks=\toks27
\pgfmath@stack@operand=\toks28
\pgfmath@stack@operation=\toks29
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code
.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigonomet
ric.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.random.cod
e.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.comparison
.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.
tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code
.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.
tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integerari
thmetics.code.tex)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count106
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.code.te
x
File: pgfcorepoints.code.tex 2013/10/07  (rcs-revision 1.27)
\pgf@picminx=\dimen125
\pgf@picmaxx=\dimen126
\pgf@picminy=\dimen127
\pgf@picmaxy=\dimen128
\pgf@pathminx=\dimen129
\pgf@pathmaxx=\dimen130
\pgf@pathminy=\dimen131
\pgf@pathmaxy=\dimen132
\pgf@xx=\dimen133
\pgf@xy=\dimen134
\pgf@yx=\dimen135
\pgf@yy=\dimen136
\pgf@zx=\dimen137
\pgf@zy=\dimen138
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconstruct.
code.tex
File: pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex 2013/10/07  (rcs-revision 1.29)
\pgf@path@lastx=\dimen139
\pgf@path@lasty=\dimen140
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage.code
.tex
File: pgfcorepathusage.code.tex 2014/11/02  (rcs-revision 1.24)
\pgf@shorten@end@additional=\dimen141
\pgf@shorten@start@additional=\dimen142
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.code.te
x
File: pgfcorescopes.code.tex 2015/05/08  (rcs-revision 1.46)
\pgfpic=\box30
\pgf@hbox=\box31
\pgf@layerbox@main=\box32
\pgf@picture@serial@count=\count107
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicstate.c
ode.tex
File: pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex 2014/11/02  (rcs-revision 1.12)
\pgflinewidth=\dimen143
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransformation
s.code.tex
File: pgfcoretransformations.code.tex 2015/08/07  (rcs-revision 1.20)
\pgf@pt@x=\dimen144
\pgf@pt@y=\dimen145
\pgf@pt@temp=\dimen146
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.code.tex
File: pgfcorequick.code.tex 2008/10/09  (rcs-revision 1.3)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.code.t
ex
File: pgfcoreobjects.code.tex 2006/10/11  (rcs-revision 1.2)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathprocessing
.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex 2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.te
x
File: pgfcorearrows.code.tex 2015/05/14  (rcs-revision 1.43)
\pgfarrowsep=\dimen147
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.code.tex
File: pgfcoreshade.code.tex 2013/07/15  (rcs-revision 1.15)
\pgf@max=\dimen148
\pgf@sys@shading@range@num=\count108
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.code.tex
File: pgfcoreimage.code.tex 2013/07/15  (rcs-revision 1.18)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.code.
tex
File: pgfcoreexternal.code.tex 2014/07/09  (rcs-revision 1.21)
\pgfexternal@startupbox=\box33
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.code.te
x
File: pgfcorelayers.code.tex 2013/07/18  (rcs-revision 1.7)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransparency.c
ode.tex
File: pgfcoretransparency.code.tex 2013/09/30  (rcs-revision 1.5)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.code.
tex
File: pgfcorepatterns.code.tex 2013/11/07  (rcs-revision 1.5)
)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex
File: pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex 2014/03/21  (rcs-revision 1.35)
\pgfnodeparttextbox=\box34
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.tex
File: pgfmoduleplot.code.tex 2015/08/03  (rcs-revision 1.13)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-0-65
.sty
Package: pgfcomp-version-0-65 2007/07/03 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
\pgf@nodesepstart=\dimen149
\pgf@nodesepend=\dimen150
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-1-18
.sty
Package: pgfcomp-version-1-18 2007/07/23 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.1)
)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
Package: pgffor 2013/12/13 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.25)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex)
\pgffor@iter=\dimen151
\pgffor@skip=\dimen152
\pgffor@stack=\toks30
\pgffor@toks=\toks31
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex
Package: tikz 2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.151)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothandlers
.code.tex
File: pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex 2013/08/31 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.20)
\pgf@plot@mark@count=\count109
\pgfplotmarksize=\dimen153
)
\tikz@lastx=\dimen154
\tikz@lasty=\dimen155
\tikz@lastxsaved=\dimen156
\tikz@lastysaved=\dimen157
\tikzleveldistance=\dimen158
\tikzsiblingdistance=\dimen159
\tikz@figbox=\box35
\tikz@figbox@bg=\box36
\tikz@tempbox=\box37
\tikz@tempbox@bg=\box38
\tikztreelevel=\count110
\tikznumberofchildren=\count111
\tikznumberofcurrentchild=\count112
\tikz@fig@count=\count113

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.code.tex
File: pgfmodulematrix.code.tex 2013/09/17  (rcs-revision 1.8)
\pgfmatrixcurrentrow=\count114
\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn=\count115
\pgf@matrix@numberofcolumns=\count116
)
\tikz@expandcount=\count117

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tik
zlibrarytopaths.code.tex
File: tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex 2008/06/17 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.2)
)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.tex
\@xs@message=\write4
\integerpart=\count118
\decimalpart=\count119
)
Package: xstring 2013/10/13  v1.7c  String manipulations (C Tellechea)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty
Package: calc 2014/10/28 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
\calc@Acount=\count120
\calc@Bcount=\count121
\calc@Adimen=\dimen160
\calc@Bdimen=\dimen161
\calc@Askip=\skip46
\calc@Bskip=\skip47
LaTeX Info: Redefining \setlength on input line 80.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \addtolength on input line 81.
\calc@Ccount=\count122
\calc@Cskip=\skip48
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tik
zlibrarypositioning.code.tex
File: tikzlibrarypositioning.code.tex 2008/10/06 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tik
zlibraryfit.code.tex
File: tikzlibraryfit.code.tex 2013/07/12 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.5)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tik
zlibrarycalc.code.tex
File: tikzlibrarycalc.code.tex 2013/07/15 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.9)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tik
zlibraryarrows.code.tex
File: tikzlibraryarrows.code.tex 2008/01/09 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.1)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryarrows.code.
tex
File: pgflibraryarrows.code.tex 2013/09/23 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.16)
\arrowsize=\dimen162
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tik
zlibrarydecorations.markings.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tik
zlibrarydecorations.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduledecorations.cod
e.tex
\pgfdecoratedcompleteddistance=\dimen163
\pgfdecoratedremainingdistance=\dimen164
\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentcompleteddistance=\dimen165
\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentremainingdistance=\dimen166
\pgf@decorate@distancetomove=\dimen167
\pgf@decorate@repeatstate=\count123
\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude=\dimen168
\pgfdecorationsegmentlength=\dimen169
)
\tikz@lib@dec@box=\box39
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/decorations/pgflibrary
decorations.markings.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tik
zlibraryshapes.misc.code.tex
File: tikzlibraryshapes.misc.code.tex 2008/01/09 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.1)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/shapes/pgflibraryshape
s.misc.code.tex
File: pgflibraryshapes.misc.code.tex 2013/07/18 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.5)
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tik
zlibraryshapes.geometric.code.tex
File: tikzlibraryshapes.geometric.code.tex 2008/01/09 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.1
)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/shapes/pgflibraryshape
s.geometric.code.tex
File: pgflibraryshapes.geometric.code.tex 2008/06/26 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.1)

))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tik
zlibraryshapes.symbols.code.tex
File: tikzlibraryshapes.symbols.code.tex 2008/01/09 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.1)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/shapes/pgflibraryshape
s.symbols.code.tex
File: pgflibraryshapes.symbols.code.tex 2013/09/11 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.6)
))
\pgf@layerbox@background=\box40
\pgf@layerboxsaved@background=\box41
\msc@box=\box42
\actionheight=\skip49
\actionwidth=\skip50
\bottomfootdist=\skip51
\msccommentdist=\skip52
\conditionheight=\skip53
\conditionoverlap=\skip54
\envinstdist=\skip55
\firstlevelheight=\skip56
\gatesymbolradius=\skip57
\hmscconditionheight=\skip58
\hmscconditionwidth=\skip59
\hmscconnectionradius=\skip60
\hmscreferenceheight=\skip61
\hmscreferencewidth=\skip62
\hmscstartsymbolwidth=\skip63
\inlineoverlap=\skip64
\instbarwidth=\skip65
\instdist=\skip66
\instfootheight=\skip67
\instheadheight=\skip68
\instwidth=\skip69
\labeldist=\skip70
\lastlevelheight=\skip71
\leftnamedist=\skip72
\levelheight=\skip73
\lostsymbolradius=\skip74
\markdist=\skip75
\measuredist=\skip76
\measuresymbolwidth=\skip77
\mscdocreferenceheight=\skip78
\mscdocreferencewidth=\skip79
\referenceoverlap=\skip80
\regionbarwidth=\skip81
\selfmesswidth=\skip82
\stopwidth=\skip83
\timerwidth=\skip84
\topheaddist=\skip85
\topnamedist=\skip86
\c@mscinstcnt=\count124
\c@condition=\count125
\c@msclevelcnt=\count126
) (./tmp.aux)
\openout1 = `tmp.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
 ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count127
\scratchdimen=\dimen170
\scratchbox=\box43
\nofMPsegments=\count128
\nofMParguments=\count129
\everyMPshowfont=\toks32
\MPscratchCnt=\count130
\MPscratchDim=\dimen171
\MPnumerator=\count131
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count132
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks33
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2016/05/15 v2.6 Base part for package epstopdf

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty
Package: grfext 2016/05/16 v1.2 Manage graphics extensions (HO)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvdefinekeys.sty
Package: kvdefinekeys 2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty
Package: etexcmds 2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
)
Package etexcmds Info: Could not find \expanded.
(etexcmds)             That can mean that you are not using pdfTeX 1.50 or
(etexcmds)             that some package has redefined \expanded.
(etexcmds)             In the latter case, load this package earlier.
)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2018/01/21 v0.26 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty
Package: ifpdf 2017/03/15 v3.2 Provides the ifpdf switch
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: LuaTeX not detected.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
)
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 4
38.
Package grfext Info: Graphics extension search list:
(grfext)             [.pdf,.png,.jpg,.mps,.jpeg,.jbig2,.jb2,.PDF,.PNG,.JPG,.JPE
G,.JBIG2,.JB2,.eps]
(grfext)             \AppendGraphicsExtensions on input line 456.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Liv
e
))
! Undefined control sequence.
\GenericError  ...                                
                                                    #4  \errhelp \@err@     ...
l.19 \end
         {msc}
? X
 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 15439 strings out of 492982
 326082 string characters out of 6134897
 396101 words of memory out of 5000000
 18744 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 5138 words of font info for 19 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 66i,6n,110p,433b,965s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
No pages of output.
PDF statistics:
 3 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: don't use the minimal class, for many things it is too minimal. And put braces around subscripts: `\CMAC_{\s{k}}`, leaving that out is wrong syntax and can break.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer -- I updated the mwe, thank you for the advice.

Comment: works fine for me. if you still get errors, show the complete log-file.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer -- The mwe is giving the error on the last 2 messages that were commented; if you didn't uncomment the lines then the error doesn't occur. I updated the mwe by uncommenting the lines, and added the log file.

Comment: sorry hadn't seen the remark about the development version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The development version uses e-tex but not consequently. You could try this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{msc}

\makeatletter
\def\msc@selfmess#1#2#3{%
  \IfStrEq{\mscget{label position}}{left}{\xdef\msc@tempc{-1}}{\xdef\msc@tempc{1}}
  \xdef\msc@tempb{[\mscget{label position},/msc,message,message loop={#3},
            \ifmsc@isstar replay,\fi, inner sep=0pt,
           /tikz/pos=\mscget{pos}, every message, \msc@options]
           (#1)
              to node[xshift=\msc@tempc*\mscget{label distance}](msc@lastnode){\unexpanded\expandafter{\msc@mess@name}}
           (#2);
          }%use macro to expand parameters
}
\makeatother
\newcommand*{\s}[1]{\mathit{#1}}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\CMAC}{CMAC}
\begin{document}
\begin{msc}{mwe}
    \declinst{A}{}{A}
    \declinst{B}{}{B}
    \mess{$\CMAC_{\s{k}}(x)$}{A}{B}  % works
    \nextlevel
    \mess{$\CMAC$}{A}{B}             % works
    \nextlevel
    \mess{$x$}{B}{B}                 % works
    \nextlevel
    \mess{$\CMAC$}{B}{B}           % FAILS
    \nextlevel
    \mess{$\s{fails}$}{B}{B}       % FAILS
\end{msc}
\end{document}
```